# How to set browser window size using Phantom JS + Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, phantomjs

I am working on **PhantomJS** with Java for one of my project. I am looking for some help in working with **PhantomJS** in following scenario.

**Scenario:**

**Step-1:** Mouse hover on tab/link then 2 sub-links will display

**Step-2:** Click on 2nd sub-link (This element is not visible if width is less than 992)

Here in **Step-2**, I am failing due to page is not displaying the element. I have tried following ways to resolve:

1. Added wait statement before clicking (Explicit wait -> wait until element clickable)

> Note: Script getting failed in this step due to element is not clickable.

2. Set the custom window size (1920 X 1080)

> Note: Here my query is when I used driver.window.maximize(), I am getting window size as "1366 X 768". So I am not sure whether it will work if I set the window size as "1920 X 1080".

Please share your experiences or idea's to resolve this issue. Your help/suggestions are very helpful to me

> NOTE: I am facing this issue only PhanjomJS browser only in remaining all browsers are working fine

Comment: It should work. You can check by yourself. Try to make a screen-shot and check its dimension.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I tried it but still getting same error. So I am not sure whether it is resizing or not

Comment: So waht is your screen-shot showing? Is the element really ontside of the viewport (to the left or to the right or above or below)? Or it presents on the screen-shot?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Screenshot shows that elements disturbed due to the size and showing like a mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Given some `WebDriver`, one can modify the dimensions of the window-size of the `WebDriver` leveraging a method comparable to the one below.

```
public static void setWindowSize(WebDriver driver, int width, int height) {
      Dimension dm = new Dimension(width, height);
      //Setting the current window to that dimension
      driver.manage().window().setSize(dm);
}
```